# How to place images in a row based on the given count in html5 canvas using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How to place images in html5 canvas in a row based on no.of images given dynamically and how distribute space between the rows, where the no.of rows are also given dynamically?

Comment: more info are needed, like what you have tried what is the expected result in an image

Comment: I placed images in three rows with 100pts space between each row in html5 canvas. In first row I have 3 images, in second row I have 2 images and in third row I have 5 images. I need to give equal space between the images in the row based on the canvas width. The space between the images in the row varies due to the no.of images placed in each row. How do I do it? Are there any predefined methods to do the process?

Comment: the width and height of the images is predefined? and if yes which is it

Comment: Yes they are predefined, width:80, height:100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do layout as simple as that in javascript, you can just do it yourself. The example below evenly spaces the rows based on the height of the canvas, and then within each row, the rectangles are evenly spaced by the width of the canvas. You can resize the browser and watch how the layout moves the rectangles around.

```js
var imageHeight = 100;
var imageWidth = 80;

//This defines how many pictures are in each row
var rowCount = [
2,
3,
5
];

setCanvasSize();
redrawCanvas();

function setCanvasSize() {

 var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

 var width = window.innerWidth;
 var height = window.innerHeight;

 can.width = width;
 can.height = height;

}

function redrawCanvas() {
 var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = can.getContext("2d");

 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

 var width = can.width;
 var height = can.height;
  
  //
  // This is the layout function ------------------------
  //
  
  //how many pixels per row are available?  
  var pixelsPerRow = height/rowCount.length;
  
  for (var y=0;y<rowCount.length;y++) {
   //draw the yth row:
    var imagesInRow = rowCount[y];
    var pixelsPerImage = width / imagesInRow;
   for (var x=0;x<imagesInRow;x++) {
     
      //now find the center of the cell defined by the 
      //x and y coordinates:
      
      var xC = (x * pixelsPerImage) + (pixelsPerImage / 2);
      var yC = (y * pixelsPerRow) + (pixelsPerRow / 2);
      
      //now place the image in the center of the cell by offsetting half of the image's width and height:
      
      var xI = xC - (imageWidth / 2);
      var yI = yC - (imageHeight / 2);
      
      //instead of drawing an image, for this example a rectangle is being drawn instead:
      
     ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
     ctx.fillRect(xI, yI, imageWidth, imageHeight);
      
    }    
  }
}

window.onresize = function() {
 setCanvasSize();
  redrawCanvas();
};
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Kiefer, your coding helped me in finding the solution.